# How to replace one line in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim, regex

I have an ipv6 hosts file. No I want to add a comment symbol # to each line that having "google.com.hk".

How could I do this in vim? I thought it would be something like `%s/^.*google\.com\.hk/^#???/`.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `&` in the replacement text to stand for the whole original string:

```
%s/^.*google\.com\.hk/#&/
```

or, to avoid replacing things like `not-google.com.hk` and `google.com.hk.example.com`:

```
%s/^.*[ .]google\.com\.hk\( \|$\)/#&/
```

Alternatively, use the `g` command to apply an `s` command to all matching lines:

```
g/[ .]google\.com\.hk\( \|$\)/ s/^/#/
```

Comment: what about `\<` and `\>` word boundary assertions?

Comment: @Philip: They would help only if `.` and `-` were word constituent characters, which is not the case by default (and would render `b`/`e`/`w` not usefully different from `B`/`E`/`W`).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
%s/\(^.*google\.com\.hk\)/# \1/
```

This tells VIM to search for what's in the parentheses, in this case `^.*google\.com\.hk`, and put that into the `\1` variable.  Then you replace all that you found before with `#` followed by `\1`.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
%s/^.*google\.com\.hk/# &/
```

Where the `&` is shorthand for *whatever was just matched*